# How can I copy and paste a method in node.js given only the methods name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a codegen project and I have a problem that I thought would be simple, but it appears it is not.  I need to take in a method name, go to a js file, copy that method (and only that method) and insert that method in another file.  Copy and pasting is fine if that is what it takes.  The idea is to read a document with the annotated descriptions of the methods, search a directory, grab the methods and put each one beneath their annotations.  Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a task that can be accomplished using a JavaScript parser that could give you an AST of that method, and also that could compile it back to JavaScript.

Probably *Babel* is a good candidate for this:

- [babel/parser](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser)
- [babel/generator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-generator)

Comment: So if I hade a file, let's call it index.js just to be simple, and it has a method in it called "methodOne" babel can give me everything that I need to generate that method's signature in another file?

Comment: @user3593210 100%